# How to display address without XSS issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.2.x and I have following code in view.

```
<%= order.address.address_array.join('<br />').html_safe %>
```

address is an array of address1, address2, city name, state name, country name and zip code - standard stuff.

Since I am marking the content as `html_safe` if user enters `<script>something</script.` in city name then that javascript code will be executed.

What is a clean way to show address with line break without exposing security issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call html_safe on each lines of your address array before joining. It should looks like that (not tested):

```
<%= order.address.address_array.map(&:html_escape).join('<br />') %>
```

Comment: This is also marking the user input data (city name) as html_safe. Not good. Right ?

Comment: yes, i think you're right. Try jdoe solution or use .map(&:html_escape) instead of .map(&:html_safe)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
simple_format(h(address))
```

It'll escape scripts and then will add `<br/>` instead of newlines.